# Unbound Identifier “ ’ ”

Tags: scheme, racket

When I try to execute this code:

```
((lambda (a) (cons (quote a) a)) ’(d a b))
```

I get an error:

> ’: unbound identifier in module in: ’

Can someone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 5):

It's a simple error, instead of the `’` character you must use `'` for quoting. It's possible that you copy-pasted the wrong character from somewhere else! Copy the code from here and you'll see that it works:

```
((lambda (a) (cons (quote a) a)) '(d a b))
=> '(a d a b)
```

Comment: I think this is a common error when copying from carelessly typeset code listings, where the wrong character is used.